# Migrating a three-tier Java desktop app to web: how to make only Presentation layer's View in React and keep the rest in Java?

Tags: java, reactjs, web

I want to migrate a Java desktop app to web, using React on the front-end and putting everything on Microsoft Azure cloud, but I'm only making first steps in these topics.

It's easy to find in the web suggestions to build a standard Java+React web app with back-end in Java (usually powered by Spring) and React GUI calling the back-end via some HTTP API. **If my app is a 3-tier app (presentation layer with MVC / business logic / data storage), do I understand correctly that the above essentially means that the first layer would be fully substituted with a totally rewritten React app, while the other two would remain in Java and with only slight changes (addition of HTTP API) become the back-end?**

If so, I see some disadvantages:

- *In the presentation layer I would prefer to make as little work as possible; only substitute ugly Swing views with something nice and modern, not much more. But instead I find myself forced to rewrite also the GUI logic, controllers etc. - and this in a language I don't know well (i.e., Java Script).*
- *I have some utility functions and libraries used by both presentation and business layer (containing, for example, certain pojos or functions operating on files). If I move the first layer completely to React, this means I will need to duplicate these tools in JavaScript, which will be time-consuming and error-prone.*

Are my observations correct? If so, **may I split my desktop app in two: client (current presentation layer) and server (business and data layer), in a way that in the client, out of my current MVC only the View part will be rewritten in JavaScript, while Model and Controller will remain in Java?** How to do it?

After some search I only see the following possibilities:

1. Creating front-end not with pure React, but GWT or Vaadin framework integrated with pieces of React.
2. Using a transpiler (JSweet?) to translate my Java code to JavaScript.

However, I wouldn't like to add one more framework to learn and depend on, especially one that seems not very actively developed and supported. And using a transpiler has it's limitations, better to be avoided.

*If justified, I could consider choosing some other popular framework like Angular or Vue over React.*

Answer (score 1):

## Just Java with Vaadin

With [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com), you may be able to very easily **recreate your existing [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) views**. The concepts of widgets and layout managers are quite similar. You can use straight Java code that reads similarly to Swing code. Alternatively, you can use [their commercial visual-editor product](https://vaadin.com/designer).

A Vaadin app lives on the server, both UI and business logic written in Java and executing in [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) on server.

Vaadin automatically generates the HTML/CSS/JavaScript necessary to render your forms remotely in the web client using standard Web technologies. User events (mouse clicks, tabbing between fields, etc.) are automatically transmitted back to server Java code to run your Java code in response.

No need for [*React*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) at all, as Vaadin handles transparently the [single-page-app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) manipulation. No need for you to write any JavaScript at all.

Vaadin works with [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) and [Jakarta CDI](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/). Or you may choose to use plain [Jakarta Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet).

See the Vaadin Ltd company page, [*SWING TO VAADIN*](https://vaadin.com/application-migration/swing) overview for migrating Swing apps to Vaadin Flow.

Vaadin deploys on top of standard Java with standard Jakarta Servlet technologies. So you can certainly deploy to the cloud such as Microsoft Azure as you mentioned, as shown in the company's [tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/azure).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you did a great job in planning for the changes.
First, I think you need to separate the presentation logic from the business logic as a best practice in MVC, the business layer cant call the presentation layer or depend on it at all so that you can then change the presentation layer as you want with no concerns.

More Reading : [MVC Martin Fawler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController)

And I think that there will be no duplication when separating them as you will be conforming to the Single Responsibility Principle & removing the coupling between layers.

So whether you choose GWT(Not Recommended) or a front end framework this separation is mandatory.

Read About [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) too for front end

Comment: Please elaborate why "Not Recommended".

Comment: It's not common and not easy to learn for new team members